# How to replicate a table 100 times and add it back to the original table

Tags: sql

I just started using SQL and need to perform the following task. 
1) First, I need to dupicate a table 100 times. For all these duplicated tables, I want to keep its content unchanged. But I also want to update the primary key by one.
2) Secend, I want to concatenate all these duplicated tables together by row, and also concatenate them to the original table by row.

Example: The original table looks like:

ID  CATEGORY

1       A

2       B

…       …

26  Z

And I want to duplicate this table, and concatenate it to the original one. I want to maintain the colums other than the primary key (ID here) unchanged, and update the primary key by one each time. I want to get:

ID CATEGORY

1    A

2    B

...

26   Z

27   A

...

52   Z

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something?  I can't see any practical reason to duplicate data like that with this weird set of requirements.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)